# State machine - state transition diagram for double delay discrete time machine

Tags: state-machine

I am working my way through an MIT OCW course, [Introduction to Electrical Engineering and Computer Science I](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-01sc-introduction-to-electrical-engineering-and-computer-science-i-spring-2011/index.htm), in which state machines are employed.  I have noticed that the course instructors do not draw state transition diagrams for most of the state machines they discuss.

One problem is to design & Python code a state machine whose state is the input from two time intervals in the past.  I think that this is an infinite state machine for which a state transition diagram might be useful for getting the general idea while showing only a few of the states.

I am wondering if a state transition diagram can be drawn for such double delay machine.  All the examples, so far, have a transition line emerging from a state bubble marked with an input and the resulting output and then pointing at the next state.  For a double delay machine the input of consequence is entered two time periods previous.  The [problem instructions](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-01sc-introduction-to-electrical-engineering-and-computer-science-i-spring-2011/unit-1-software-engineering/state-machines/MIT6_01SCS11_2_1_3.pdf) state that all **state** memory for the machine be in one argument.  No mention is made of input memory, which I would think necessary.

My questions:

1. Can a state transition diagram be drawn for this state machine?
2. Is it necessarily the case that input memory be a part of this design?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to draw a diagram since the set of all possible states includes any value of any data type, given in the example for the (single) delay state machine in the readings. So the number of possible states can't be defined. See [Chapter 4: State Machines](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-01sc-introduction-to-electrical-engineering-and-computer-science-i-spring-2011/unit-1-software-engineering/state-machines/MIT6_01SCS11_chap04.pdf).

In the problem description it states that:

> It is essential that the **init** and getNextValues methods in any state machine not set or read any instance variables except self.startState (not even self.state). All memory (state) must be in the state argument to getNextValues. Look at the examples in the course notes, section 4.1.

So the state is all the memory you need. There is no reason not to use an array as state to keep the last two inputs.

First we save both values in memory (state)

```
class Delay2Machine(StateMachine):
    def __init__(self, val0, val1):
        self.startState = (val0, val1)
```

Following the super class SM step function implementation also given in the readings:

```
def step(self, inp):
    (s, o) = self.getNextValues(self.state, inp)
    self.state = s
    return o
```

The output will be the first of the values saved in memory, and the state will be updated to include the new input

```
    def getNextValues(self, state, inp):
        return ((state[1], inp), state[0])
```